# Don't write file with csv DictWriter if there is no data

Tags: python, csv, generator, writer

I have a Python (3.4) routine that writes a `csv` file using a generator. However, depending on the parameter set, there may not be any data, in which case, I don't want the `csv` file to be written. (It would just write the file with a header only).

Right now, the bandaid is to count the lines after generation and then delete the file, but surely there must be a better way, while retaining the pattern of having a generator being the only code that's aware of whether there is data for the given parameters, (nor having to call on the generator twice):

```
def write_csv(csv_filename, fieldnames, generator, from_date, to_date, client=None):
  with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(generator(from_date, to_date, client))

  # If no rows were written delete the file, we don't want it
  with open(csv_filename) as f:
    lines = sum(1 for _ in f)
    if lines == 1:
      f.close()
      os.remove(f.name)


def per_client_items_generator(from_date, to_date, client):
  return (per_client_detail(client, sales_item) for sales_item in
        sales_by_client.get(client))
```

Comment: You might also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661603/how-do-i-know-if-a-generator-is-empty-from-the-start or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114252/one-liner-to-check-whether-an-iterator-yields-at-least-one-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use itertools to take a look at the first item and then sort of put it back into the generator:

```
import itertools
gen = generator(from_date, to_date, client)
try:
    # try to get an element
    first = next(gen)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    # run this if there was no exception:
    gen = itertools.chain([first], gen)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(gen)
```

This is a little shorter, but may be harder to read:

```
import itertools
gen = generator(from_date, to_date, client)
try:
    # pop an element then chain it back in
    gen = itertools.chain([next(gen)], gen)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    # run this if there was no exception:
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(gen)
```

Or this doesn't use visible `try`/`catch` code (although there's probably an equal amount down inside `next()`):

```
import itertools
sentinel = object()  # special flag that couldn't come from the generator
gen = generator(from_date, to_date, client)

# try to get something
first = next(gen, sentinel)
if first is not sentinel:
    # got a meaningful item, put it back in the generator
    gen = itertools.chain([first], gen)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(gen)
```

(These were inspired by Stephen Rauch's answer, but with a few tweaks.)

Comment: Yeah, but now I'm worried about how to avoid catching StopIteration errors that bubble up somehow from the code after first(). Might have to define a helper variable...

Comment: I think that's basically what I did. For a minute I thought I'd need to set a helper variable after getting first(), to indicate whether it succeeded. Then I remembered `try`/`except`/`else`, which is perfect for this.

Comment: I was originally going with the else in my code, but wasn't sure where the OP was at, so went a bit simpler.  The Chain is clever...

Comment: Thanks! Just noticed that a couple of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661603/how-do-i-know-if-a-generator-is-empty-from-the-start are similar to mine, but so it goes!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of *preview* the generator using `next()`, being careful to preserve the first generated value, with something like:

```
csv_gen = generator(from_date, to_date, client)
try:
    first_item = next(csv_gen)
except StopIteration:
    csv_gen = None

if csv_gen is not None:
     # prep for write csv
     ....         

    # write csv header
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    # write item already read from generator
    csv_writer.writerow(first_item)        

    # write rest of generator
    csv_writer.writerows(csv_gen)
```

Please note that this was not tested, so may contain silly typos.

Comment: `next` doesn't *preview* the generator, it *advances* it. You'll lose that data!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for the heads up, but the data is preserved, check the code.  I tried to put *preview* in italics, but used it for lack of a better word...

Comment: Perhaps "scare quotes" would be appropriate?