# Directory listener query

Tags: java, excel, file-io

I am writing an application where a human user / a service will write excel files to a particular directory. Now the program will always listen to directory changes , will parse this excel and will try to convert this into a xml file based on a schema.  Now I have few custom exceptions like

- InvalidFileException
- InvalidFormatException
- MissingDataException

etc.

I want to know is it a good idea to drive logic based on the exceptions?
Means if it throws InvalidFile exception I want to execute some logic ..
I am using WatchService from java 7

Comment: My understanding is that that is exactly what exceptions are for: to capture a defined but unwanted result and try to act in consequence. Otherwise you would not try to catch exceptions at all.

Comment: Not an good idea - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378005/when-is-it-ok-to-use-exception-handling-for-business-logic

Comment: finally written logic in catch blocks. To avoid any type of memory usage issue every time launching a new jvm instance from cmd prompt from a batch file

Answer (score -1):

That is why they are there.  If you need it then use it and there is nothing wrong with it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html

Comment: @Downvoter For this kind of file handling adding business logic to the catch block is completly okay.