# Last element in xml not getting picked up

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have a python 3 script below that is supposed to download an xml file and split it into smaller files with only 500 items each. I am having two problems:

1. the last item in the original xml is not present in the split files
2. if the original xml was 1000 items long it will create a 3rd empty xml file.

Can anyone tell me where there could be such an error in my code to cause these symptoms?

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from lxml import etree

def _yield_str_from_net(url, car_tag):

    xml_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    for _, element in etree.iterparse(xml_file, tag=car_tag):
        yield etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8')
        element.clear()

def split_xml(url, car_tag, save_as):

    output_file_num = 1
    net_file_iter = _yield_str_from_net(url, car_tag)
    while True:
        file_name = "%s%s.xml" % (save_as, output_file_num)
        print("Making %s" % file_name)
        with open(file_name, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as the_file:
            for elem_count in range(500):    # want only 500 items
                try:
                    elem = next(net_file_iter)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
                the_file.write(elem)
                print("processing element #%s" % elem_count)
        output_file_num += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    split_xml("http://www.my_xml_url.com/",
              'my_tag',
              'my_file')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is no error but by design. After reading 1000 elements the iterator does not yet know that there is no further item and thus continues with the `while True` loop.

It would be great if iterators would have a [`hasNext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966591/hasnext-in-python-iterators) then you could replace it by `while hasNext` in order to overcome this issue. Unfortunately there is no such thing in python.

For the first question: currently I can't see anything in your code explaining this issue.