# How to detect generator end explicitly in Python?

Tags: python, generator

I wrote a generator, which returns tuple of values:

```
import numpy as np

def mygenerator():
    data = np.arange(10)
    data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 2))
    for row in data:
        yield row[0], row[1]

generator = mygenerator()
while True:
    a, b = generator.__next__()
    print("a: ", a, "b: ", b)
```

and want to use it without `for ... in`. How detect end of generation then?

Comment: Just keep calling `next` on it and manually catch `StopIteration`?

Comment: Bit of info in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413978...

Comment: I know it may be an annoying question, but why can you not use a for loop? Mind showing us a bit more code to see if it is really impossible?

Comment: Am also a bit surprised to learn what is probably the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966609/4288043) to this question.

Comment: [In Python 3, you should now be calling `next(generator)`, not `gen.__next__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next). So you shouldn't need to detect generator end, explicitly. This syntax has an optional `next(generator, None)` to make iterating with for-loops cleaner.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The generator will throw an exception `StopIteration` when it is exhausted. You can catch the exception with `try`…`except` statement and exit loop when it occurs:

```
while True:
    try:
        a, b = next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print("a: ", a, "b: ", b)
```

BTW, why not `for` loop? It seems that:

```
for a, b in generator:
    print("a: ", a, "b: ", b)
```

does exactly what you want, without cumbersome constructions.

Comment: I can't use `for ... in` because in my real code I use complex processing of returned values and switching different loops...

Comment: @Dims ok you say you have a complex use-case which makes it hard for you to use a for-loop. But it's still recommended idiom. You could simplify it by defining helper subiterators, and/or chaining them. Post a new question showing that code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be by using the *default* parameter of [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) built-in function as a breaking condition. Once the generator is exhausted, instead of throwing a `StopIteration` exception, the default value will be emitted.

```
# ...

gen = mygenerator()

stop_value = None # or another value
while True:
    v = next(gen, stop_value)
    if v is stop_value:
        break
    print("a: {}, b: {}".format(*v))
```

Answer (score -1):

Stumped into this and suggest do following, generator will exhaust until `next()` returns `None`:

```
import numpy as np

def mygenerator():
    data = np.arange(10)
    data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 2))
    for row in data:
        yield row[0], row[1]

generator = mygenerator()
a, b = next(generator, None)
while a and b:
    print("a: ", a, "b: ", b)
    a, b = next(generator, None)
```