# Iterator for k-combinations

Tags: python, algorithm, iterator, combinations, backtracking

[LeetCode 77. Combinations](https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations):

> Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers chosen from the range [1, n].
> You may return the answer in any order.

My code using backtracking is given below.

```
def combine(n: int, k: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    def backtrack(i: int, comb: list[int]) -> None:
        if len(comb) == k:
            ans.append([*comb])
            return
        # Number of elements still needed to make a k-combination.
        need = k - len(comb)
        # The range of numbers is [i, n], therefore, size=n - i + 1
        remaining = n - i + 1
        # This is the last offset from which we can still make a k-combination.
        offset = remaining - need
        for j in range(i, i + offset + 1):
            comb.append(j)
            backtrack(j + 1, comb)
            comb.pop()

    ans: list[list[int]] = []
    backtrack(1, [])
    return ans
```

It works as expected.

Now, I'm looking at [LeetCode 1286. Iterator for Combination](https://leetcode.com/problems/iterator-for-combination/), which basically asks for an `Iterator[list[int]]` or `Generator[list[int]]` instead of returning all the combinations at once.

> Technically, LeetCode 1286 works with strings, but for the sake of similarity to LeetCode 77, let's talk about integers only, since it makes no difference to the algorithm.

Can the above code be converted to return an iterator? The reason I'd prefer starting with the above code and not something completely different is because of its simplicity, and to keep the two solutions similar as much as possible.

**My research efforts:**

I've studied the sample code for [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), but it works differently from my code above, and, IMO, is pretty convoluted since it uses some obscure/non-intuitive features such as `for-else` and loop variables referenced later (Python loop variables remain in scope even after the loop exits).

I've also looked at [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127704/839733), but due to the highly generic nature of the question (it doesn't specify a programming language or whether the combinations should be returned all at once or as an iterator), the answers are all over the place.

Finally, I've looked at [Creating all possible k combinations of n items in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12991758/839733), which specifies C++, but not an iterator, and thus, doesn't fit my purpose, since I already know how to generate all combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass yielding through recursion with minimal changes to your code.

1. Yield `comb` if length is appropriate instead of appending it to `ans`.
2. Yield everything `backtrack(j + 1, comb)` yields after each recursive call.
3. Return `backtrack(1, [])` from `combine_iterator`.

```
def combine_iterator(n: int, k: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    def backtrack(i: int, comb: list[int]) -> None:
        if len(comb) == k:
            yield [*comb]
            return
        # Number of elements still needed to make a k-combination.
        need = k - len(comb)
        # The range of numbers is [i, n], therefore, size=n - i + 1
        remaining = n - i + 1
        # This is the last offset from which we can still make a k-combination.
        offset = remaining - need
        for j in range(i, i + offset + 1):
            comb.append(j)
            yield from backtrack(j + 1, comb)
            comb.pop()

    return backtrack(1, [])
```

Checking the type of returned object:

```
type(combine_iterator(5, 3))
>> generator

type(next(combine_iterator(5, 3)))
>> list

type(next(combine_iterator(5, 3))[0])
>> int
```

Checking that the results are the same for `combine` and `combine_iterator`:

```
for n in range(2, 20):
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        res = combine(n, k)
        res_it = combine_iterator(n, k)

        assert list(res) == list(res_it), f"!!! Different results for n={n}, k={k}"

print("Done!")
```

Output:

```
Done!
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost identical to RomanPerekhrest@ code, so, it’s a close call for me which one to accept. Please see my follow up comment to his answer.

Comment: Storing the generated result kills the idea of generators. Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966591/hasnext-for-python-iterators) about `hasnext` for Python generators (which does not exist, but there's a way you can simulate it). You can try and catch `StopIteration` for `next(..)` and if it's caught - return `False`, otherwise save the value returned from `next(..)` to use further.

Comment: “_save the value returned from next(..) to use further_” is exactly what I meant by storing the generated result.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate intermediate variables and rely on `yield`/`yield from`:

```
def combine(n: int, k: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    def backtrack(i: int, comb: list[int]) -> None:
        if len(comb) == k:
            yield [*comb]
            return
        # Number of elements still needed to make a k-combination.
        need = k - len(comb)
        # The range of numbers is [i, n], therefore, size=n - i + 1
        remaining = n - i + 1
        # This is the last offset from which we can still make a k-combination.
        offset = remaining - need
        for j in range(i, i + offset + 1):
            comb.append(j)
            yield from backtrack(j + 1, comb)
            comb.pop()

    return backtrack(1, [])
```

---

Sample run:

```
print(list(combine(5, 3)))
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: I like this, since it requires minimal changes to my original code. One follow up, how to tell if there are more combinations to generate (has_next)? I guess one way would be to keep a counter since we know what nCk is, another way is to call the generator and store the result.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, to check if a generator has items: with consuming a potential item `next(gen, None)`, without consuming an item the basic idea is https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967037/3185459

Comment: The answer at the link calls `next` from `hasnext`, which is the 2nd option I mentioned above in my comment.

Comment: I accepted Maria K's answer purely based on the fact that they posted it before you, and that their code is identical to yours, so, there's no discernible difference in quality. Thank you for taking the time to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is the working solution for "LeetCode 1286. Iterator for Combination" based on the answers I received. Note that the `hasNext` method in the question has been renamed to `has_next` to comply with Python naming convention.

```
class CombinationIterator:
    def __init__(self, characters: str, combination_length: int):
        self._s = characters
        self._n = len(characters)
        self._k = combination_length
        self._it = self._combination(0, [])
        self._next = ""

    def _combination(self, i: int, comb: list[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
        if len(comb) == self._k:
            yield "".join(comb)
            return
        # Number of elements still needed to make a k-combination.
        need = self._k - len(comb)
        # The range of numbers is [i, n], therefore, size=n - i + 1
        remaining = self._n - i + 1
        # This is the last offset from which we can still make a k-combination.
        offset = remaining - need
        for j in range(i, i + offset):
            comb.append(self._s[j])
            yield from self._combination(j + 1, comb)
            comb.pop()

    def next(self) -> str:
        if not self._next:
            return next(self._it)
        nxt = self._next
        self._next = ""
        return nxt

    def has_next(self) -> bool:
        if self._next:
            return True
        try:
            self._next = next(self._it)
            return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False
```