# implicit memory consumption with itertools.tee of generators

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm using the answer(s) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661603/how-do-i-know-if-a-generator-is-empty-from-the-start) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467430/python-generator-with-check-for-empty-condition?lq=1) to check if my generator `x` is empty.

```
from itertools import tee
def my_generator():
    yield from range(100000000)
x = my_generator()
x, y = tee(x)
try:
    next(y)
except StopIteration:
    # x is empty do something
    quit()
```

What will happen to the elements extracted from `x`? can they be *discarded* ? or must be kept in memory for `y`?

```
# now consume x entirely
for z in x:
    print(x)
# how can y iterate over its objects ?
# will they have to reside in memory now ??
```

Comment: What `y` are you referring to? Do you mean `z`? The elements "yielded" from the generator can be discarded after use. The generator is just a "lazy list" that you have to call every time you want an element from it.

Comment: @MortenJensen thanks, I fixed the typo - the problem is that since both x and y are now "dependent" on 'x', what happens when its elements are "gone"?

Comment: Your post still refers to an `y` which confuses me. A generator is a sort of "function" that returns items one at a time. When you're done iterating through them, the generator is "spent" and you must re-create the generator to iterate over the item-collection again. Nothing happens to the collection itself, the generator is just an abstraction over the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - elements yielded from `x` will be kept in memory until they are yielded from `y` as well.

When using `itertools.tee`, copies of all the yielded elements must be saved for the all the iterators returned from `tee`.
In your case, those are `x` and `y`.

This is done to allow full iteration through both `x` and `y`.

If you look at the equivalent implementation in the [Python docs for `itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), you can see that all yielded values are saved until they are yielded from all the generators `tee` returned.

In your case, you'll have to consume both `x` and `y` or have them (both) go out of scope and garbage-collected for the items to be released.

Comment: I was testing in the python console and the objects are not destroyed even if they are yielded from all iterators. They only are destroyed when the iterators are deleted. I tried with gc.collect()