# Python execute code only if for loop did not begin iteration (with generator)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

The `else` block in a `for`/`else` clause gets executed if the iteration finishes but is not interrupted by `break`, [so I read](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Is there a language construct which would let me write something which executes only if the `for` loop did not begin iteration? If I was using a `tuple` or `list`, I would do something like this:

```
if seq:
    for x in seq:
         # something
else:
    # something else
```

But when I use a generator, I don't get the behavior I want:

```
>>> g = (x for x in range(2))
>>> for x in g:
...     print x
... else:
...     print "done"
... 
0
1
done    # I don't want "done" here
>>> g = (x for x in range(2) if x > 1)
>>> if g:
...     for x in g:
...         print x
... else:
...     print "done"
... 
>>>     # I was expecting "done" here
```

How can I do this without exhausting creating a `tuple` or a `list` from the generator, while also using a `for` loop? I could use `next()` in a `while` loop and try to catch `StopIteration`, but I'd like to see if there's a nice way to do it with `for`.

Comment: I'd probably set a `ran` flag inside the loop and use `if not ran:`.

Comment: You can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661603/how-do-i-know-if-a-generator-is-empty-from-the-start

Comment: @Ludo I know that I can't know if a generator is empty to begin with. I was just wondering if there's a nice language construct to handle this case.

Comment: Great question. Came here for the same thing. I've been writing Python for > 7 years and just wanted to know if there was some syntactic sugar hiding in the language that I'd never discovered. Alas, there is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't think of a better way than updating a boolean inside the for loop.

```
any_results = False
for x in g:
    any_results = True
    print x
if not any_results:
    print 'Done'
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd do that normally; I just wanted to know if there was a control structure or some other language construct which did this succinctly.

Comment: This is just like having a counter.Can't we use for...else provided by python?

Comment: @shadow0359 - I don't see how, `for...else` on an empty `g` will exit with `true`.

Answer (score 6):

```
n = -1
for n, i in enumerate(it):
    do_stuff()
if n < 0:
    print 'Done'
```

Comment: i like the use of `enumerate`.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution much better.Check this link for more info(http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html).

You can use a custom sentinel:
x = no_data = object()

```
x = no_data = object()
for x in data:
    .......
if x is no_data:
    print "Loop did not run"
```

object() returns a featureless object which is a base for all classes.

is checks if both the objects are same(x is no_data).If they remain same ,means the control never went to the for loop.

Comment: I think this may have some risks when x = no_data both points to a generator, cause a generator will exhaust after the for-loop.

Comment: At first, `x` and `no_data` both point to an `object` instance. `data` is the generator from which `x` takes values from. If the loop ran then `x` will have changed and `x is no_data` will be surely False. In my opinion, there's no risk into it.

Comment: @Menglong what is the risk you are refering to?

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution for `for` loops. IMHO calling the sentinel object `no_data_sentinel` would make the code more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator function:

`next` accepts an optional second argument, that can be used to specify a default value in case the iterator has exhausted.

```
def func(lis):
    g = (x for x in lis if x > 1)
    flag = object()      # expected to be unique
    nex = next(g, flag)  # will return flag if genexp is empty
    if nex is not flag:
        yield nex
        for item in g:
            yield item
    else:
        yield "done"

for x in func(range(2)):
    print x
print "------"
for x in func(range(4)):
    print x
```

**Output:**

```
done
------
2
3
```

Comment: How does this compare in efficiency with memory and of course execution time to either the boolean approach or doing `tuple(g)`?

Comment: @2rs2ts As iterators have some extra overhead so they are going to be slow compared to the boolean approach, but an advantage is that you can access limited number of items(i.e slicing) using `itertools.islice` without iterating over the all items(if needed in any case), you can't so that with a simple for-loop. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results) for comparison between tuple/list and genexp.

Comment: That is *very* cool. I'll be using list comprehensions more often for smaller data sets now. Anyway, for my purposes since I do not need any slicing or other forms of iteration, I'll be doing the boolean approach. But between your answer and your comment this was incredibly useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice way to know if the loop actually executed is by using a loop variable

```
lv= 1
for x in g:
    lv = lv+1
    print x
if (lv == 1):
    print 'Done'
```

My syntax might be wrong, cos I'm not a python guy..

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper that counts the number of iterations. It has the advantage that it works with more exotic enumerations. In python3, it would be something like:

```
import sys
from glob import iglob

class GenCount(object):

    def __init__(self, gen):
        self._iter = iter(gen)
        self.count = 0

    def __next__(self):
        val = self._iter.__next__()
        self.count += 1
        return val

    def __iter__(self):
       return self

c = GenCount(iglob(sys.argv[1]))
for fn in c:
    print(fn)
print(c.count)


c = GenCount(iglob(sys.argv[1]))
print([fn for fn in c])
print(c.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether x was defined in the loop.

```python
for x in (y for y in range(2) if y > 1):
    print(x)

try:
    print(f'do something with {x}')
except NameError:
    print('the loop did not run')
```

However, make sure that x is not defined before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When the `else` branch is an expression (or a sequence of expressions) with side-effect, you can use the short-circuit property of the boolean operators. For instance, this Python 3 function:

```py
def print_items_or_nothing(items):
    if items == []:
        print("nothing")
    else:
        for item in items:
            print(item)

print_items_or_nothing([])          # prints "nothing"
print_items_or_nothing([1, 2, 3])   # prints "1", "2", "3"
```

... can be rewritten as:

```py
def print_items_or_nothing(items):
    for item in items or print("nothing") or []:
        print(item)
```

##### Explanation

This technique leverages the fact that `or` evaluates and returns its right operand if and only if the left one is falsy.

Consider the expression `items or print("nothing") or []`:

- If `items` is non-empty, it is truthy, so the rest of the expression is not evaluated, and the result is `items`.
- If `items` is empty, it is falsy, so `print("nothing")` is evaluated... to `None`, which is falsy, so `[]` is evaluated and constitutes the result, which is iterable (as required).

##### Advantages

- no modification of the loop body;
- no auxiliary variable;
- lightweight.

##### Drawbacks

- limited to the cases where the `else` branch contains no instruction (although you certainly can use a walrus operator for added unreadability);
- clever ;)

Answer (score -1):

In the example here, do you need an extra construct?

```
caught = None
for item in x:
    caught = item
    print caught
if caught != None: print "done"
```

*Edited for OP commen*t

Comment: Nah, I want it to only print `"done"` if it didn't have anything to iterate over.