# Most elegant way to branch if a generator is empty in Python

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator in Python, and I want to loop over it if it has items, and perform a different action if it is empty. Something like

```
if generator is empty:
    perform some action
else:
    for item in generator:
        perform some actions
```

I know there is no way to tell if a generator is empty without iterating through it, but it seems that there should still be some nice elegant way to perform this logic. The best I can think of is something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/664239/161801, which seems very inelegant, I guess because it has to treat the first element of the generator separately from the rest.

Comment: You could iterate over all the items and set a flag ("there was an item") inside the loop and do the alternate action if the flag was not set

Comment: @njzk2 I obviously know about that question (I linked to it), but I think it is different. That question is asking if it is possible to know if a generator is empty without iterating through it. I already know that this is not possible due to the way that generators work. I am asking for a clean way to work with this limitation.

Comment: @asmeurer there are several different answers and approaches in the linked question - what are your problems with them? This doesn't really seem like a separate question.

Comment: @asmeurer the answer you linked to is as good as it gets I'm afraid

Comment: This is what I initially thought (and sometimes wish) that `for else` meant in Python. Unfortunately it means something a little different.

Comment: @asmeurer all the options are in the duplicate - Python hasn't evolved  a new way of doing what you want since that was answered...

Answer (score 4):

Just set a flag if the generator is not empty:

```
isGeneratorEmpty = True
for item in generator:
    isGeneratorEmpty = False
    perform some actions

if isGeneratorEmpty:
    perform some actions
```

Comment: [Source?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7971996/1454048)

Comment: @admdrew The logic is pretty straightforward (someone suggested the same thing in the comments), jh314 probably came up with it independently.