# Detect last record in standard input (stdin) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading input through `stdin` (hadoop streaming in reducer).

I need to detect when last record comes in. I am running for loop on `stdin` data.

I tried to read the `stdin` first to calculate the total records and then again read to proceed with business processing, but as soon as I read a record from `stdin`
to calculate `total_cnt` then the records goes out from the stream and later when I try to read `stdin` for processing there is no record in `stdin`.

```
total_cnt = 0 

for line in stdin:  
    total cnt += 1

for line in stdin:  
   ##Some Processing##
```

I don't want to store `stdin` to somewhere and read data from that location twice (1. total record count and 2. data processing).

Is there any way I can detect when last record comes in from `stdin`?

I am using python version 2.7.11 and need to implement this in approach in Hadoop reducer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24199042/5987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the previous line each time you take in a new one. When the loop exits, `line` will have your last, unprocessed line to do with as you please.

Example:

```
old_line = None
for line in range(10):
    if old_line is None:
        old_line = line
        continue  # skip processing on the first loop: we'll make it up after
    print "Do stuff with: %i" % old_line
    old_line = line
print "Double last line: %i" % (line*2)
```

which gives:

```
Do stuff with: 0
Do stuff with: 1
Do stuff with: 2
Do stuff with: 3
Do stuff with: 4
Do stuff with: 5
Do stuff with: 6
Do stuff with: 7
Do stuff with: 8
Double last line: 18
```