# Detect if generator function is empty, otherwise iterate over it

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, iterable

Let us suppose we have a generator function `gen()`, which we do not know if it is empty or not.

If it is empty, we would like to execute a special function `foo()`, and otherwise we would like to execute a function over each element of the iterator `bar(elem)`.

I can do it like this:

```
is_empty = True
for elem in gen():
    is_empty = False
    bar(elem)
if is_empty: foo()
```

But that does not feel very pythonic. Any other approach?

Comment: Your approach isn't terrible, btw. It's pythonic enough. Generally, you shouldn't care whether a iterator is empty, or rather, this should be known by the results of iterating over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell directly whether a generator is empty. This is by design. A key principle behind generators is they do not hold in memory all items of a generated sequence.

But you can do something like this:

```
from itertools import chain

def check_first_and_iterate(iterable):
    try:
        first = next(iterable)
        for item in chain([first], item):
            bar(item)
    except StopIteration:
        foo()

check_first_and_iterate(iterable)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`peek`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/664239/4909087) function:

> ```
> import itertools
> def peek(iterable):
>     try:
>         first = next(iterable)
>     except StopIteration:
>         return None
>     return first, itertools.chain([first], iterable)
> ```

---

```
res = peek(gen())
if not res:
    foo()
else:
    for elem in res[1]:
        bar(elem)
```

You will still need to peek into the generator, but you can do it cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to exhaust the generator before traversing its items, and your function `foo()` returns `None`, you may consider doing this:

```py
for elem in list(gen()) or foo() or []:
    bar(elem)
```

The `or` operator evaluates its second operand only when the first one is falsy.