# How to know if query doesn't return documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I know if docs is empty? I can't do `len(docs)`

```
docs = query.stream()
for doc in docs:
    // do something
```

I need to know if there is no document that matches the query

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the .to_dict() method and then using len() on the dictionary returned ?

Comment: I get this error '`generator' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`

Answer (score 2):

Since `stream()` [returns a generator](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/query.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.query.Query.stream), there won't be a trivial way to determine if it is empty without actually reading it.

By far the simplest solution would delay knowing until after you are past the loop.  Something like this:

```py
docs = query.stream()
stream_empty = True
for doc in docs:
  stream_empty = False
  # do something

if stream_empty:
  print("it was empty")
else:
  print("it wasn't empty")
```

Otherwise, you get into having to build your own generator around the stream's generator that allows peeking.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661603/3399890).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the generator returned by `stream()` you can directly use the query and its method `get()`.

The get method runs the query and gathers the documents within a list that you can access. This list is empty if no document matches the query.

```py
docs = query.get()
if not docs:
    # do something
else : 
    for doc in docs :
        doc = doc.to_dict()
        # do something
```