# Standard way in Python to find if element of iterable is last?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

If I'm looping through Python's iterator, how can I find out if now is the last element? I'm looking for some standard library way of doing this, maybe some function in `itertools`, is there such? Or some other very short and Pythonic way of doing this.

Of cause I can implement my own helper generator achieving this task:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCgIxDETv/Yoct7A3PQle/QLvUthUA6UtaRT262uzrSuCc5y8MDN5lUeKh1oX9EDlFlyRicSeDDR54iJwhis/sRuJAYEikHRCRR5ikg5/XdVKGBa4uFBwhsz42q/YrF/2k7XR@0WfmtmN/0E9RCuODKMtdcg8uo5Z7OIdp6Md4zJTlGlw1tT6Bg)

```
def is_last(it):
    first = True
    for e in it:
        if not first:
            yield False, prev
        else:
            first = False
        prev = e
    if not first:
        yield True, prev

for last, e in is_last(range(4)):
    print(last, e)
```

Which outputs:

```
False 0
False 1
False 2
True 3
```

Also if I'm looping through simple range I can always compare to upper limit (below is solution for positive `step`):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYwxDoAgFEN3T9ERIoPIZoJ3YUD9iQECf/H0CDja4S19bXr4isHUWthlVigcU6dPsNCLwqoVzHTEDAIFZBdOL36y3Ca03K5w2xHm72K3wxldyhRYdEOBZK0v)

```
start, stop, step = 10, 21, 3
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    last = i + step >= stop
    print(last, i)
```

Which outputs:

```
False 10
False 13
False 16
True 19
```

This above is also obvious and probably easiest solution for the case of simple range, unfortunatelly it needs keeping stop/step in separate variables. But anyway range-case is not very interesting. What about the case of any arbitrary iterator, is there a Pythonic way to solve this case?

Comment: There's no way to know. Some iterators don't have a last element, or they generate elements dynamically so there's no way to tell until you try to get it.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that you have to get it. That's why I provided my own solution helper generator `is_last()` which gets element in advance. But I wanted to know if there is some function for doing this in `itertools` library?

Comment: There are forms of infinite iterarators in Python such as `while True: yield something` where there just is no last element.

Comment: @dawg After looking at his `is_last` iterator, I can see that he's OK with it always returning `false` in such cases.

Comment: @dawg I don't want to get last element. I just want to know if current element is last or not. If it is infinite iterator then a function should just always return False for the question of `is last?`.

Comment: Actually I solved it already through my `is_last()` generator. I just wanted to know if there is such function already in `itertools` or other standard libraries.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in itertools that does this. Note that your solution is always reading the original iterator one step ahead of the caller. This could potentially be a problem with some iterators, e.g. reading a file.

Comment: E.g. if you use `for last, line in is_last(file)` and then do `file.seek(0)`, you'll read the line after where you seek.

Comment: @Barmar There is no way to tell in advance that it is last element, so caller of my function `is_last()` should be aware that it may cause problems of read-ahead.

Comment: Which is why there's no standard library for this, it doesn't generalize well.

Comment: @Barmar Understood! Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this before.  It's not a great solution because it's easy to misuse, but it could work.

```
def peek(itr: Iterator[T]) -> Tuple[Optional[T], Optional[Iterator[T]]]:
    """
    Return a pair of (first element of iterator, new iterator).  If iterator is exhausted, return (None, None).
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/664239/3282436

    NOTE: Because checking for values consumes part of the supplied iterator, that iterator is invalidated.  To continue
          iterating, you *must* use the iterator returned from peek.

    >>> itr = iter(range(3))
    >>> if recipes.peek(itr)[0] == 0:  # WRONG, itr will be missing first element
    >>>     # ...

    >>> itr = iter(range(3))
    >>> first, itr = recipes.peek(itr)  # Correct
    >>> if first == 0:
    >>>     # ...
    """
    try:
        first = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        return None, None
    return first, itertools.chain([first], itr)
```