# How do I check if a filter returns no results in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, iterable

I have a filter function that I use to clean certain items out of a list:

```
def filterOutPatternMatches(objList, matchKey, matchPatterns):

   def checkPatterns(obj):
      delete_it=True
      for pat in matchPatterns:
          matchString=obj[matchKey]
          if pat.search(matchString):
              delete_it=False
              break

      return delete_it

  result = filter(checkPatterns, objects);
  return result
```

It works fine, except that there is no easy way for me to find out if the filter() function has returned an empty iterable.
I want to know if the list is empty, and if so, do one thing.  If not, do something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know if a generator is empty from the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661603/how-do-i-know-if-a-generator-is-empty-from-the-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to approach this:

1. Convert the filter object to a list, then check if it is empty:

```
     l = list(filterObject)
     if (len(l) == 0):
        # The filterObject is empty, do the empty thing
```

The problem is that you have to convert the filterObject iterable to a list, which is potentially a very expensive operation if the iterable is very large.

2. Use next() to pull the first item off of the filter object iterable.  If there is nothing in the list, you will get a StopIteration error, which you have to catch.
   You will also need to process the first item outside of the rest, since you can't put it back on the iterable.

```
try:
   firstItem = next(filterObject)
   # Do whatever you need to do with the first item in the filterObject iterable
except StopIteration:
   # Do whatever you do if there are no filter results

for o in filterObject:
   # Now handle the rest of the filter results
```

Problems with this: you have to handle the first item outside of your for loop, which is annoying.  If you want to run some aggregation function on the filterObject iterable, you have to deal with the one item that you pulled off separately.  Very un-pythonic.

3. Iterate over the filterObject as you normally would, but set a flag if it is empty:

```
     filterObject = filter(someFunc, someIterable)
     itWasEmpty=true
     for x in filterObject:
         itWasEmpty=false
         # Process the filterObject items

     if itWasEmpty:
         # Do whatever you do if it's empty.
```

Cons:  You need to process the entire list manually.  Can't pass the filter object to an aggregation function.

That's all I can come up with!