# Python get the last element from generator items

Tags: python

I'm super amazed using the generator instead of list.
But I can't find any solution for this question.

What is the efficient way to get the first and last element from generator items?
Because with list we can just do lst[0] and lst[-1]

Thanks for the help. I can't provide any codes since it's clearly that's just what I want to know :)

Comment: The only way to know what's at the end of a generator sequence is go through the whole thing.

Comment: I see. Or I can just try and catch the StopIteration?

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/q/661603/5987 but it won't be as efficient as `[-1]`.

Comment: Generators don't necessarily have a last item, either. Consider `(i for i in itertools.count())`. (Or just `itertools.count()` if you don't want to nitpick over the difference between a generator and an iterator.)

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks I think I can also get some idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to iterate through the whole thing. Say you have this generator:

```
def foo():
    yield 0
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
```

The easiest way to get the first and last value would be to convert the generator into a list. Then access the values using list lookups.

```
data = list(foo())
print(data[0], data[-1])
```

If you want to avoid creating a container, you could use a for-loop to exhaust the generator.

```
gen = foo()
first = last = next(gen)
for last in gen: pass

print(first, last)
```

Note: You'll want to special case this when there are no values produced by the generator.

Comment: This is great. since I don't want to convert them to list, The first=last=next(gen) is what I'm looking for. 
I tried and it worked. Thank you very much